# Windows 10 crashing on virtual machines

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, bsod, vmware

I have a six-month old computer with Intel Core i7-7700 Kaby Lake and 16 GB of RAM.  I use Debian 9.1 (Stretch) as my main OS and it's quite smooth and stable.

I need to use Windows 10 in a virtualized environment for work, and it keeps crashing for all sorts of reasons, both in VMware Workstation and VirtualBox.

BSOD reasons I've seen:

- PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
- BAD_POOL_HEADER
- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

Does anyone have any idea what could have been causing this?

Comment: These should be generating .dmp files.  Those dmp files can be analysed with windbg to determine the cause.  The reasons alone is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: What version of VMware Workstation are you using?

Comment: And along the lines of what Ramhound, if you're not familiar with windbg, you alternatively could use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to better identify the source of the crash.